# How can I replace text that is not part of an anchor tag in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, text, anchor

What is a Perl regex that can replace select text that is not part of an anchor tag?  For example I would like to replace only the last "text" in the following code.

```
blah <a href="http://www.text.com"> blah text blah </a> blah text blah.
```

Thanks.

Comment: gulp.  Regex and html.  goes to hide...

Comment: Aren't the first and last two "blahs" also "not part of an anchor tag?"

Comment: @Jay - I assume the OP wants to `magic_replace(html, 'text', 'link still ok')`

Comment: @Jay: Presumably he's doing `s/text/replacement/g`, so the blahs don't match.  But this is not a job for a regex (alone).

Comment: Ah... got it. Yes, refer to the seminal text on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: It is said that in Ulthar, which lies beyond the river Skai, no man may parse html with a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have temporarily prevailed:

```
$html =~ s|(text)([^<>]*?<)(?!\/a>)|replacement$2|is;
```

but I was dispirited, dismayed, and enervated by the [seminal text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454); and so shall pursue Treebuilder in subsequent endeavors.

Comment: Use of regex html parsers will cause you to wind up like Charles Dexter Ward.

Comment: Your regex will also replace the "text" inside `<a><i>text</i></a>`, because it only looks at the first end tag.

Comment: it depends on what you're parsing - if they are small, regular lines of HTML output by another process for example, then a regex might be appropriate. if they are actual full HTML pages, then a proper HTML parser makes sense...

Answer (score 8):

You don't want to try to parse HTML with a regex.  Try [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TreeBuilder) instead.

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $html = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file('file.html');
# or some other method, depending on where your HTML is

doReplace($html);

sub doReplace
{
  my $elt = shift;

  foreach my $node ($elt->content_refs_list) {
    if (ref $$node) {
      doReplace($$node) unless $$node->tag eq 'a';
    } else {
      $$node =~ s/text/replacement/g;
    } # end else this is a text node
  } # end foreach $node

} # end doReplace
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regexps for this kind of stuff. Use some proper HTML parser, and simply use plain regexp for parts of html that you're interested in.